# Getting wrong value of time stamp while using Gregorian Calendar in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, datetime

I'm working with **time picker and date picker dialog** in Android. For saving **DATE and TIME** I'm using **INTEGER** data type in Sqlite. So I made few utility functions to convert **DATE** from Date Picker Dialog to **LONG(TIMESTAMP)** format and converting those back to user readable **DATE**. But somehow they are giving me the wrong result.

```
//Date Picker OnDateSetListener
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String dateText = getTimeString(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
        long date = Utility.getDateLong(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
        taskModel.setEndDate(date);
         endDateView.setText(dateText);
    }
};

 private String getTimeString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
    Log.i("set_date",monthOfYear+"");
    String yearText = String.valueOf(year);
    String monthText = String.valueOf(monthOfYear);
    String dayText = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
    return dayText+"/"+monthText+"/"+yearText;
}

//Utility Functions
//Getting long(TIMESTAMP) from DATE

public static long getDateLong(int year, int month, int day){
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        long timeStamp = date.getTime();
        return timeStamp;
    }

//Converting TIMESTAMP to DATE
 public static String getDateFromLongValue(long d){
    Date date = new Date(d);
    //Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    //calendar.setTimeInMillis(d);
    //return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    return formattedDate;
}
```

I'm getting the wrong TIMESTAMP for the DATE that I entered. For example if the enterd DATE is 09-06-2016("dd-MM-yyyy") the converted long value is -876215232 which when converted back to date gives 22-12-1969.

Moreover when I'm selecting the DATE from picker I'm getting wrong month. i.e if I'm selecting 9th;July;2016, The **monthOfYear** property I'm getting 6 instead of 7.
Can someone please point the mistake.

Comment: Gregorian calendar month start from 0 to 11 i.e. January is 0th month of year in this calendar. Check Java documentation. That is why you are getting 6 instead of 7  which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the value you pass for the month to the `GregorianCalendar` constructor is 0-based as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int,%20int,%20int)).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 31 );  // 1 = January.
```

- Use [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) counts months as you would expect: 1-12.
- Store as `YYYY-MM-DD` text rather than as timestamp.

## Details

The [Answer by MPelletier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338371/642706) is correct, you did not follow the documentation telling you that month is zero-based counting (0-11) rather than one-based (1-12). Crazy behavior, yes. One of *many* reasons to avoid these poorly designed old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

### java.time

Instead you should be using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` & `java.util.Calendar`. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. The month number is sane, 1-12.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 31 );
```

Or use the handy [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 31 );
```

### Parts of date

You can interrogate for each part, year, month, and day-of-month.

```
int year = localDate.getYear();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```

### Time zone

When capturing the current date, be sure to specify a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneID );
```

### ISO 8601

Using a count-of-milliseconds-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) does not make sense for a date-only value. Given that SQLite has [no true data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), and nothing to support SQL standard DATE columns, I suggest storing a String that represents the date value. Specifically, create a String in the formats defined by the ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes use this standard’s formats by default when parsing and generating Strings. The standard format of `YYYY-MM-DD` happens to sort alphabetically as chronological.

```
String string = localDate.toString(); // 2016-01-31
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( string );
```

If using JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, you may be able to pass the `LocalDate` via `getObject`/`setObject` on a `PreparedStatement`.

## Summary

So `LocalDate` compared to the old classes is:

- More logical (sane month counting 1-12)
- Easier to work with Strings (directly parse/generate standard format)
- Truly represents a date-only value

Comment: How can it be used to perform date operations such as finding the time elapse between two dates if I'm storing LocalDateTime in form of String?